# C# interface declaration for Generic/template class

Tags: c#, templates

I'm not sure how to create the interface declaration for Generic/template class. See code snippet below. I have choice of constraining T/V from interface declaration at the get go - OPTION 2 below, or not constraining it at all - but then I can't declare the private collections of **_beans**.

**OPTION 1** - no constraining from interface, then trouble is I dont know how to do the interface

```
public class SomeService 
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IBeanContainer> _beansContainers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IBeanContainer>();

    private interface IBeanContainer
    {
        // How to declare interface ...
    }

    private class BeanContainer<T, V> : IBeanContainer
        where V : struct where T : class
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IBean<T,V>> _beans =  new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IBean<T,V>>();

        public IBean<T,V> GetOrCreateExpressionCounter<X,Y>
        (
            string beanName,
            TimeSpan span,
            ExpressionEval<T, bool> include = null,
            ExpressionEval<T, V> valueExpression = null)
        {
            return _beans.GetOrAdd(counterName, counter => new ExpressionCounter<T, V>(beanName, span, include, valueExpression));
        }
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2:** Constrain T/V at interface, then I don't know how to declare the private collection _beans

```
private interface IBeanContainer

        {
            IBean<T, V> GetOrCreateExpressionCounter<T, V>
            (
                string counterName,
                TimeSpan span,
                ExpressionEval<T, bool> include,
                ExpressionEval<T, V> valueExpression) where V : struct where T : class;
        }
```

Then from BeanContainer needs be declared without , and I cant declare the internal dictionary of **_beans**:

```
private class BeanContainer : IBeanContainer
            where V : struct where T : class
        {
            private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IBean<T,V>> _beans =  new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IBean<T,V>>();
 ...
}
```

But at least with OPTION 1 I can compile the code, but not proper (Cant declare interface).

Comment: And what runtime error do you get when trying to instantiate the Dictionary?

Comment: Option 1 - no error. Option 2, not proper (as no interface)

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace in the original question instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the interface in your case? Are you going to expose some common functionality with it? What functionality is that?

Comment: Yes - it's to make it very generic (at the same time very abstract and difficult). I can't paste stack (It's proprietary code)

Comment: Have you tried adding the generics to both the class and the interface? `IBeanContainer<T, V> where V : struct where T : class` and `BeanContainer<T, V> : IBeanContainer<T, V> where V : struct where T : class` not sure if this is something you want to do from a design perspective but that way both the interface and the class can use the T and V types

Comment: KNoop - I tried adding <T,V> to both class and interface: I didnt do that as I deliberate want to have collection of different types of _beansContainers

Comment: So lets say you manage to do this and implement just a `IBeanContainer` without any type information and store implementations of this interface in a collection. How are you going to determine which T and V types any specific implementation is for? I think there's a design problem here, as soon as you try to put all different types in a single collection you lose the type information when working with that collection. Feels like saying 'I want a collection that stores both int and string and some class', sure you can (`List<object>`) but you lose the functionality of the entries